# From mathematics to economical interpretation

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm having trouble getting some intuition beneath the sheer maths of the following toy model:
\begin{align*}
(IS) : y_t &= -\eta r_t^e\\
(B) : r_t^e &= -\delta y_t + r_t
\end{align*}

Where $r_t$ is the real interest that applies for household, and $r_t^e$ is the real interest that applies for firms only. Given our IS curve, we assume that household do not care about $r_t$, so that aggregate demand $y_t$ is only a function of $r_t^e$ (i.e. firms do care about interest rate). Our $(B)$ equation states that bank lend money to firms based on the general level of GDP : the higher $y_t$, the lower $r_t^e$.

Now the following bugs me : you would believe that higher $r_t$ will deter $y_t$ (as it usually does). But in fact, if $\eta $ is high enough, one has :
\begin{align*}
y_t = \frac{\eta}{\eta \delta - 1}r_t
\end{align*}
Therefore, if $\eta \delta > 1$, we might end up with a positive relation between $r_t$ and $y_t$. Now what I don't know, is how to explain this appart from just stating "math" fact, i.e. I'm looking for an "economical explanation". What I know so far is :
\begin{align*}
y_t = \delta \eta y_t + r_t
\end{align*}
Therefore if $\delta \eta $ is high, we have more that a *one-to-one multiplicative effect*. But that doesn't explain to me why, given some possible value of $\eta$ and $\delta$, one might end up with a situation where **a rise** in $r_t$ will cause **a fall** in $r_t^e$, appart from stating the obvious maths behind it.